# OneToOneField in Django

Tags: django, model, one-to-one

I have written a view that let me store some datas in a database:

```
def save(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    user = request.user
    p = SavedProduct(username= user, product_off_id=product.off_id)
    p.save()
```

This is my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2000)        
    off_id = models.BigIntegerField()      

class SavedProduct(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    product_off_id = models.BigIntegerField()
```

It does the job but I am struggling to implement a `OneToOneField` to `username` and `product_off_id`.

I know `product_off_id = models.BigIntegerField()` should be `product_off_id =models.OneToOneField(Product)` but what should I pass in `p=SavedProduct()` for the `product_off_id` field?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with the `OneToOneField` it would be:

```
p = SavedProduct(username= user, product_off_id=product)
```

Comment: Works perfect but what about OneToOneField on my username?

Comment: `username = models.OneToOneField('Product', to_field='name')`